Footprints in the Snow
I found some mysterious footprints in the snow and transcribed them as best I could.
Who walked past?

Text version:
..- --- . -..- -..- .... -. -..- . - . .. .. . -

Shouldn’t the cipher tag be on here?

Given the accepted answer, the "Who walked past" should be "Who or what walked past".

The lack of a cipher tag confused me for a while. I mean, obviously this puzzle involved Morse code, right?! Not so.
Upon getting nowhere with a Morse translation I tried to think 'outside the box'. What might leave 'footprints' of these shapes? A possibility hit me...

 How about certain letters, spelling out a set of words? After all, the base of most letters is either a horizontal line (like a capital 'E') or flat-ish curve (like a 'C') - either of which might make a dash shape when 'treading' in the snow - or one or more point-like 'legs' (for 'T' or 'A', etc.), hence dots.

So, with this idea in mind, I tried to spell out some useful words. And then I laughed as it hit me... You were passed in the snow by...

 ...all the letters of the English alphabet, walking by in alphabetical order! Like so:



 Note that the precise font is crucial here, and my original monospace choice led to much discussion in the comments below, particularly concerning the merits of serif vs sans-serif fonts when focussing on the footprint of the 'I'. In this puzzle's chosen depiction its footprint is a dash rather than a dot, and so requires a line at its base - a good option that accommodates this and still matches all other letters (including having only two feet - not three - for the 'M') is Verdana; thanks to @EspeciallyLime for the suggestion.

 Away from computer font discussions, however, the footprints used in this puzzle do reflect how many people might hand-write their alphabet, top-and-tailing a letter 'I' with horizontal bars.


The "I" is somewhat problematic - in almost any font, if it has a serif, so do several other letters (like F, P, T, or Y). It should probably be a dot rather than a dash.

@NuclearHoagie When writing by pen, I've always drawn my I's with bars in essays, letters, etc., so that is how I always picture an I, but yes either works. I wonder if the bars will be dropped someday... : )

@NuclearHoagie If you're not typing in all-caps, the capital "I" needs the serifs to distinguish from a lower-case "l".  Whereas F, P, T, and Y can all be easily distinguished from other letters with or without serifs.

@DarrelHoffman Nuclear Hoagie's point is that the vast majority of sans-serif fonts don't have a serif on the I, making it a dot, whereas in a serif font (e.g. the one used in this answer) I and T both have serifs so would both be dashes. However, there are a few fonts that do match the pattern in OP, including Comic Sans and Verdana.

brilliant solution. Picking up the comments here, I'd rephrase the final sentence to "is dependent on whether you are using serif or sans-serif fonts". Clearly, here a serif font is used.
In fact, the I is the troublesome thing. If the serif on the I justifies a dash, why don't the other serifs, such as on the T? The puzzle might have benefitted from using a dot there.

Thanks all for the font discussions! @EspeciallyLime Good shout on Verdana - I've modified the image to use this instead. Comic Sans didn't quite work, though, as the 'M' touches the baseline in 3 places...

It is funny that is so hard to find a font that matches the actual way I was taught to draw the letters in grade school. I intentionally went analog in this puzzle as the fonts are referred to as a who and are walking around in the snow with feet, like an old fairy tale.

@Stiv good spot - it's a relief that the best option isn't Comic sans :)
